# What are "daddy issues"?

Tags: developmental-psychology, cognitive-development

The question is whether there exists a phenomenon in which a girl that had a bad relationship with a father (referring to a father that's too harsh, too cruel or that doesn't show love, and hates his daughter) implies that the girl will try to seek male attention and approval, when a "normal" individual would not, or a girl that seeks to be with "bad boys".

I'm interested in knowing if this has been researched and what is the name of this topic in cognitive science.

Note: I couldn't find any tag myself that fits for this question, I choosed any tag because I couldn't post, please change it if you can to something related to the question.

Comment: There is something called the Elektra complex, which is the female form of the Oedipus complex. Is that what you were aiming at?

Answer (score 4):

"Daddy issues" is not a well-defined term, however, the extrapolation of attachment style theory answers to this question somewhat.

[Relationship outcomes of different attachment styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attachment_in_adults#Relationship_outcomes)

*(this is not clearly cognitive science, and more precisely "family issues" instead of "daddy issues")*

[Stack Overflow thread about the topic](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4382/classification-of-attachment-styles/4554)

*(I'm new here, and amazed how well written are the answers :O )*
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a thesis on the effects of "daddy issues" on women's later relationships. Its content and its citations may be enough to satisfy your interest.

Jackson, L. M. (2010). Where's my daddy: Effects of fatherlessness on women's relational communication (Order No. 1477319). Available from ProQuest Dissertations & Theses Global. (577596068). Retrieved from http://search.proquest.com/docview/577596068?accountid=13314

> The purpose of this thesis research was to understand the relationship
>   between father absence and women’s communication styles in romantic
>   heterosexual relationships under social cognitive theory. Two studies
>   were conducted using a multi-method research approach in order to
>   triangulate the results. Seven fatherless women were interviewed to
>   arrive at a better understanding of how father absence informed their
>   romantic relational experiences. Specifically, the topics of
>   relationship roles, self-disclosure, expression, and self-silencing in
>   romantic relationships were examined in the interviews. Participants
>   reflected on what growing up fatherless meant to them and whether or
>   not this had any influence on the role they played (dominant,
>   submissive, egalitarian), and how open or closed they were in their
>   romantic relationships (from their own perspective). Open
>   communication refers to whether or not individuals express their
>   thoughts, feelings and needs as well as how often they express these
>   thoughts to their partners. Questions were also asked to determine
>   whether these women self-disclosed intimate details to their romantic
>   partners or self-silenced themselves. An online quantitative survey
>   (N=131) examined similar research questions and tested predictions
>   based on the results of the first qualitative study.
>
> The results from the interviews indicated that fatherless women
>   consider themselves to be open, able to easily express themselves,
>   independent and even dominant in their romantic relationships; yet
>   despite holding these characteristics, these women remained in
>   dysfunctional relationships for long periods of time. Further, when
>   self-silencing did occur, it was because they did not want to not
>   “push” their significant others away. There was also a tension between
>   wanting to hold a dominant role in their romantic relationships and
>   also being attracted to men who hold stereotypical male gender roles.
>   Hence, there was a tension with agreeing or disagreeing with these
>   socially constructed gender roles. In the second study, women who grew
>   up fatherless had a significantly less happy childhood upbringing than
>   those who had fathers. Also, in line with the results from the first
>   study, fatherless women tended towards higher scores on
>   self-disclosure, greater ease of expression, and lower scores on
>   self-silencing. Significant associations were found between negative
>   relationship with father and relational self-esteem, overall
>   self-disclosure and overall self-silencing in romantic relationships.
>   The respondents who had negative relationships with their fathers
>   self-disclosed less in their romantic relationships and self-silenced
>   more, hid their feelings more, and privileged their romantic partners
>   in communication interactions. Taken together, findings from this
>   triangulated study add to the nascent body of work examining and
>   explaining the deleterious fallout from father absence on women’s
>   communication and other variables in their romantic relationships.